# How to configure powerscan scanned documents to alfresco 5.1 repository

Tags: alfresco

I want to upload all the scanned documents to alfresco repository and they have to be distributed to their respective folders based on the metadata e.g if the docs are supplier invoices they go to the invoice folder. My scenario is they are scanned synchronized to a scan folder in the repository then upon getting into the folder they are filed into their respective folders based on the meta data.

Comment: Hi. What is your problem ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Please specify what is your problem, what have you tried what error you got while doing that , then only we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are successfully storing the documents in the Alfresco repository and your problem is that you need to automatically sort them into folders based on metadata, then what you are probably looking for is the "folder rule" functionality. You can configure a rule on a folder that triggers on metadata values and moves the documents into the folders as needed. You might be able to use the out-of-the-box rule options to match metadata criteria and then execute the move, but if you cannot for some reason, you can always tell your rule to execute server-side JavaScript. You can then write all of your logic in a server-side JavaScript file that resides in the Data Dictionary under Scripts.

If you have not gotten that far, and the problem is you don't know how to put the files in Alfresco in the first place, there are a lot of options:

- Alfresco has a built-in FTP server, so you could tell your scanning software to use FTP.
- It also has WebDAV, so you could tell it to use that.
- Or you can enable CIFS, which would allow you to mount the repository as if it were a Windows share, and then tell your scanning software to store the files in the shared mount, which is really a folder in the Alfresco repo.
- Some scanning software knows how to communicate via CMIS and Alfresco is a CMIS repository, so that's also an option.

Once you get your scanner to put the files in the repo, then everything I said earlier about rules applies.

So, step 1: Get the scanner to store the files in Alfresco. Step 2: Use a folder rule with either out-of-the-box logic or custom server-side JavaScript to sort the files into the desired folder structure.

Comment: My apologies for being a newbie. I have configured javascript api amps and I can access java script console via admin tools. My challenge is that for 'document', 'search', logger and 'companyhome' I am an receiving reference error e.g reference error 'document' is not defined. I have been reading alfresco documentation and they show that you have to access it using javascript server side. how can i do that in alfresco or how can overcome these errors.

Comment: I wanted to implement the server side javascript as indicated by Jeff Potts

Comment: I think your comment probably warrants a new topic.

Comment: Ok Jeff. I have asked another question

Comment: Here is the new post link @Jeff Potts:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582453/alfresco-java-script-api-reference-error-document-is-not-found